# HDMI with HDA Intel problem

Tags: sound, hp, hdmi, hp-pavilion

In my HP Pavilion dv7 the HDMI sound does not work (image works correctly).

I enabled this from the "Audio" panel but sound still comes out from the integrated speakers.

I tried to enable the S/PDIF-1 (I found this in some how-tos on internet) from the ALSAMIXER and also tried o update the alsa drivers, but they appear to be up to date.

I am a simple Linux user, not a guru, and I don't know now what could be the problem. Every suggestion would be appreciated.

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out **PulseAudio Volume Control** (or simply **pavucontrol**).

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

or install it via Ubuntu Software Center [image: Install via the software center]

After installation is finished, open your dash and type `pavucontrol`. Under *'configuration'* tab there should be a list of different hardware profiles. Just select the one you need an close pavucontrol.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the replt FuzzyQ. I've tried but the result doesn't change: the sound continues to come out from the laptop speakers.